# Blink text in red and black with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using javascript on some parts to modify information on page, and when the information changes, I want to blink the modified information a few times.

I've tried this, but it's not working for some reason.

```
$('.item_price').css("color" , "red").delay(500).css("color" , "black").delay(500).css("color" , "red").delay(500).css("color" , "black");
```

Comment: `.delay()` only works with animations. Try using `setTimeout()` or, better yet, don't do any annoying blinking at all.

Comment: The blinking is used so user can notice the price change.

Comment: Instead of blinking, I suggest just highlighting it with a distinct color and, after a few seconds, slowly fading it to the normal text color. Same benefits, less obnoxious.

Comment: That would be a solution, but I want to blink it.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen Wrote a small blinker plugin -> [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9rU5A/3/) and the post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12394843/297641

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) is a very weird function; used as you're using it, it only delays tasks added to the `fx` queue (and `css()` does not queue to *any* queue).

To force `css()` to queue to the `fx` queue, use the [`queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue) function;

```
$('.item_price').queue(function (next) {
    $(this).css("color" , "red");
    next();
}).delay(500).queue(function (next) {
    $(this).css("color" , "black");
    next();
}).delay(500).queue(function (next) {
    $(this).css("color" , "red");
    next();
}).delay(500);
```

... etc. Be sure to call the `next()` function (passed into the callback) to continue the queue.

For more info, I've wrote a blog post which explains exactly this, which you may find useful for further reading (as well as the jQuery documentation): http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2012/06/jquery-delay-not-working-for-you/

Comment: Thanks, just the solution I need!

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen This will work.. but I think this is too much code for a simple blink.

Comment: @Vega This is fine for me, wont be too much.

Answer (score 3):

If you're already using jQuery UI, you can do this using `.animate` which uses the queue (and `.delay` is not needed since you can specify the delay as an argument).  This has the possibly added advantage of actually animating the color change instead of just blinking.

http://jsfiddle.net/2PfL4/

Comment: I am curious to know how it works.. Does jQuery wait until it finishes first `.animate` call and then calls the next? Shouldn't those be wrapped inside callback?

Comment: No, I'm not using jquery UI on this project.

Answer (score 2):

The rather ugly code below will do this for you.

```
var item_price = $('.item_price').;

item_price.css("color" , "red");
window.setTimeout(function(){
    item_price.css("color" , "black");
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        item_price.css("color" , "red"
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                item_price.css("color" , "black");
            }, 500););
    }, 500);
}, 500);
```

Comment: Cool, but I will stick with the jquery version of this :)

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen Why? for having low-speed pages?

Comment: @undefined because jQuery is already included, and the script is based on a script in jquery, and I have no idea of most regular javascript files.

Comment: To be fair, I wasn't aware of the queue stuff, though I'd do it this way anyway as often you need to do more than just one thing in each bit.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small blink plugin with configurable parameters..

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9rU5A/3/

```
   $.fn.blink = function(o) {
        var cfg = {
            bcount: 1,       /* blink count*/
            color: 'orange', /* blink color*/
            delay: 500       /* blink delay*/
        }
       var lc = {                
            timer: null,     /* internal  */
            tCount: 0,       /* internal  */
            oColor: 'black'  /* internal  */
        };

        $.extend(cfg, o);
        lc.oColor = $(this).css('color');

        var that = this;

        var blinker = function() {
            lc.tCount++;

            if (lc.tCount > (cfg.bcount * 2)) {
                clearInterval(lc.timer);
            }
            $(that).css('color', ((lc.tCount % 2) ? lc.oColor : cfg.color));
        };

        lc.timer = setInterval(blinker, cfg.delay);
    };
```

**Caller**

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#test').blink({
        bcount: 2,
        color: 'red',
        delay: 200
    });
});
```

Comment: It's maybe a bit overkill to use a plugin for this. Good effort anyway!

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen haha you are seeing the literal meaning here.. check out the code inside and the customization factor. Anyways.. Good luck.

Comment: I did check it, and I liked it. I will probably use this if I need to blink something in future ;)